# Ordering records by created_at with time zones

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone, timestamp

I need to present an analytics chart where there's records for each hour of day. I need to have these records ordered by a datetime attributed converted to the user's current time zone which I stored in a cookie.

I tried to

```
@records.order(:created_at.in_time_zone('Sydney')
```

but what I get is undefined method error. I also tried to set a before_filter that converts the time zones, but it doesn't seem to have an effect because I order by a database column.

The reason why I need to order by time zone is because I'll also be ordering by `beginning_of_hour`, which means different order on different time zones.

Is there a way to order these records differently for each user based on their current time zone?

Thank you very much in advance

*Edit: full error message*

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms

NoMethodError (undefined method 'in_time_zone' for :created_at:Symbol)
```

Comment: Can you post your exact error?

Comment: Edited my post with the full error message

Comment: Try using like this `@records.order(:created_at).in_time_zone('Sydney')`

Comment: Still throws the same error, but this time for the ActiveRecord Relation